# JavaScript Clock

Tags: javascript, html

I ran into a snag in my code, the code below is for a JavaScript clock which works perfectly:

```
function renderTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var diem = "AM";
    var h = currentTime.getHours();
    var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var s = currentTime.getSeconds();

    if(h == 0) {
        h = 12;
    } else if(h > 12) {
        h = h - 12;
        diem = "PM";
    }
    if(h < 10) {
        h = "0" + h;
    }
    if(m < 10) {
        m = "0" + m;
    }
    if(s < 10) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    var myClock = document.getElementById('clockDisplay');
    myClock.textContent = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + diem;
    myClock.innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + diem;
    myClock.innerText = h + ":" + m + ":" + s + " " + diem;
    setTimeout('renderTime()',1000);

}
renderTime();
```

However I am trying to do it slightly different now like this:

```
function makeTime() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var diem = "AM";
    var h = currentTime.getHours();
    var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var s = currentTime.getSeconds();

    if(h == 0) {
        h = 12;
    } else if(h > 12) {
        h = h - 12;
        diem = "PM";
    }
    if(h < 10) {
        h = "0" + h;
    }
    if(m < 10) {
        m = "0" + m;
    }
    if(s < 10) {
        s = "0" + s;
    }
    var clock = document.getElementById('clock');
    clock.innerHTML = "<h1>"+h+":"+m+":"+s+":"+diem+"</h1>";
    myClock.textContent = "<h1>"+h+":"+m+":"+s+":"+diem+"</h1>";
    myClock.innerText = "<h1>"+h+":"+m+":"+s+":"+diem+"</h1>";
    setTimeout('makeTime()',1000);
}
makeTime();
```

This one works, however does not update like the other one, you have to manually refresh the page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Sidenote: use `setTimeout(makeTime, 1000);` instead of passing a string(it is a form of eval and it should be avoided)

Answer (score 3):

You continue to refer to `myClock` in your second version, when you've renamed the variable to `clock`:

```
var clock = ...
clock.innerHtml = ...
myClock.textContent = "<h1>"+h+":"+m+":"+s+":"+diem+"</h1>";
myClock.innerText = "<h1>"+h+":"+m+":"+s+":"+diem+"</h1>";
setTimeout('makeTime()',1000);
```

This is causing errors (`reference error: myClock is not defined`) which is preventing the flow of execution from reaching your `setTimeout` call.

You should learn to use the tools available to you. Every browser has a method of reporting JavaScript errors to developers. Open the developer console in Webkit/IE10, or Firebug in Firefox, you'll see these errors and exactly where they're happening in your code.